# Unable to start new nginx binary installed with ngx_pagespped

Tags: nginx, page-speed

I wanted to set up nginx with the [ngx_pagepeed](https://ngxpagespeed.com/) module. Since I already had nginx set up on my server I removed it before compiling it again using the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I built a new nginx binary with pagespeed support using the instructions given [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source).

`whereis nginx` gives the following output

```
nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/local/sbin/nginx /usr/local/nginx /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
```

Following is the output of the `nginx -V` command

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
built by gcc 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
configure arguments: --add-module=/root/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.11.33.4-beta --prefix=/usr/local/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-ipv6
```

The output of `/usr/sbin/nginx -V` is

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module
```

I updated my `nginx.conf` file withe pagespeed module settings and tried to restart the nginx server using `sudo service restart nginx` which gives me `* Restarting nginx nginx [fail]`.

If I test my new nginx settings using `nginx -t` it says the configuration is fine

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

However I find this in the error logs

```
[emerg] 24452#0: unknown directive "pagespeed" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:65
```

I read somewhere to run the following command to start the correct nginx - `sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`. This gives me the following output

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

For some reason my old nginx binary is still running and it's not letting the new binary to start. How do I run the new binary instead?

Answer (score 1):

`killall -9 nginx` then start your local one.